# MailMerge.merge_templates() function not giving the desired results (kivy/python)?

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I have created a mailmerge app using kivy for user interface and python as back-end coding language.

The app contains a main screen with  a button. Button press triggers a fileopen dialog box where the user can select desired file. The desired file is a word document with some text and place holders (merge fields).

Once the file is selected a popup opens to display:

1. Dynamically created Labels (shows merge field names created in the word document) ,
2. Dynamically created blank TextInput widgets (user needs to input the data that has to be populated in the document)
3. 2 buttons(save button - save the file in the given location; SaveAs button - user can select the desired location).

when save button is pressed, the data entered by the user in the TextInput fields gets populated in the document and saves it as a new document in default location specified.

when saveAs button is pressed, the data entered by the user in the TextInput fields gets populated in the document and triggers a saveAs dialog box where the user can select the desired location for the new file to be saved.

The issue I am facing is, on pressing the save button, data entered in the TextInput widgets by the user is getting populated in the new document only once, there is not effect when the data in the TextInput is changed and pressing save button again. The app has to be started again for changes to take effect which is not desirable. kindly help me solve this.

my code:
main.py

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.base import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from docx import *
from mailmerge import MailMerge
from datetime import date
from collections import OrderedDict
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
import os

f_path = None
merge_data = None
merge_objects = None
merge_doc = None


class doc_select(BoxLayout):
    def create_merge(self):
        global f_path, merge_data, merge_doc, merge_objects
        root = tk.Tk()
        root.withdraw()              
        f_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
        merge_doc = MailMerge(f_path)
        merge_fields = merge_doc.get_merge_fields()
        merge_data = dict.fromkeys(merge_fields)
        merge_objects = dict.fromkeys(merge_fields)
        self.show_popup()

    def show_popup(self):        
        pop = Popup(title= 'Input Details',
                    content = popup_content(), 
                    size_hint = (None,None), 
                    size = (Window.width,Window.height))
        pop.open()


class popup_content(BoxLayout):

    data_inputs = []
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def dynamic_widgets(self):
        for wid in merge_objects.keys():
            self.ids.Mybox.add_widget(Label(text = wid, size_hint_y=None))
            merge_objects[wid] = TextInput(size_hint_y = None)
            self.ids.Mybox.add_widget(merge_objects[wid])

    def create_merge_data(self):
        for i in merge_objects.keys():
           merge_data[i] = merge_objects[i].text           


    def save_func(self):
        save_path = 'C:/Users/pavan m sunder/tutorials/Kivy/py/docx/populated_doc.docx'
        self.create_merge_data()
        print(merge_data)       
        merge_doc.merge_templates([merge_data],separator='page_break')        
        merge_doc.write(save_path)
        os.startfile(save_path)


    def saveas_func(self):
        self.create_merge_data()
        print(merge_data) 
        merge_doc.merge_templates([merge_data],separator='page_break') 
        merge_doc.write(filedialog.asksaveasfilename(defaultextension='.docx', 
                                                    filetypes=(('Text files', '*.txt'),
                                                               ('doc files', '*.doc* .docx'),
                                                               ('Python files', '*.py *.pyw'),
                                                               ('All files', '*.*'))))

class docsy(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file('C:/Users/pavan m sunder/tutorials/Kivy/py/docx/sample.kv')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    docsy().run()
```

sample.kv

```
doc_select:    
    Button:
        text: 'Open'
        on_press: root.create_merge()


<popup_content>:
    orientation: 'vertical'

    ScrollView:
        GridLayout:
            cols:2
            id: Mybox
            orientation: 'vertical'
            size_hint: 1, self.minimum_height
            on_kv_post: root.dynamic_widgets()

    GridLayout:
        size_hint: 1, 0.1
        cols: 2
        Button:
            text: 'Save'
            on_press: root.save_func()
        Button:
            text: 'SaveAs'
            on_press: root.saveas_func()
```

wordfile content: sample.docx

> Welcome «Name»!                                «Date»
>   Hello «Name». This is word editing using python.
>   Go ahead and unleash your python skill.
>   «Wish»!!

Comment: The `write` command in the `MailMerge` documentation says: "Write document to file. This should be a new file, as ZipFile cannot modify existing zip files". Perhaps you need to remove the existing file before you write it a second time.

Comment: Even I saw that but I don't know how to delete/remove a file through a python code.. Kindly suggest how to do it..

Comment: I manually deleted the file and tried still not working...it works one when the app is restarted again

Comment: I expect you would need to close the file, then use `os.remove` to delete it, then re-open it.

Comment: I tried not working...please run the code and check.

Comment: When I run your code, `Microsoft Word` is started with the newly populated document. If you do not close the `Microsoft Word` app (which has the output document opened), you will not be able to overwrite that document (that is a feature of `Windows`).

Comment: please suggest python function to automatically close the file before opening it again. Thanks

Comment: The line in your code that starts `Word` is the line `os.startfile(save_path)`. How to stop the `Word` app is a different question. Could your `App` be used without starting `Word` (i.e., eliminate that line)? If you require running `Word`, then I suggest you post another question about how to close it.